# Azure Pipeline Publish: task DotNetCoreCLI with specific folder or project

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm having a problem (unwanted behavior) when running an Azure Build Pipeline with the following project/folder structure.

My repository's root folder has two main folders:

- frontend (ASP.Net Core 2.x & Angular 7 project)
- backend (ASP.Net Core 2.x)

I'm trying to build two separate Azure Pipelines one for the backend and one for the frontend, so I use the `projects:` parameter to specify the correct path.

The `build` and `test` commands are running fine and are only restoring/building/testing the `backend` folder, but the `publish` command is running for both folders: backend & frontend.

This is my yaml file:

```
 #build backend project
 task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
   name: BuildBackendProject
   inputs:
     command: build
     projects: '**/backend/**/*.csproj'
     arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

 ... #run some tests

 #publish backend project
 task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: dotnet publish backend --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
   name: PublishBackendProject
   inputs:
     command: publish
     projects: '**/backend/**/*.csproj'
     publishWebProjects: True
     arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output 
     $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/backend'
     zipAfterPublish: True
```

I tried different folder paths but it's always running two publish commands.

If I run locally in CMD `dotnet publish backend` (from repo's root folder) it works fine but apparently that doesn't work with the Azure Pipeline.

Any ideas or fixes greatly appreciated.

Comment: try using 'backend/**/*.csproj' instead of '**/backend/**/*.csproj'

Comment: @D.J. I tried with your suggestion and even using a specific project instead of a wildcard, but it's still running both publish commands. _[command]/usr/bin/dotnet publish /home/vsts/work/1/s/frontend/GaiaFront.Web.csproj_. This last command shouldn't execute if it worked like the build, test and restore commands.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The trick is in using the publishWebProjects/projects properties. Those are actually mutually exclusive. If the `publishWebProjects` is used, the `projects` property value is skipped.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/DotNetCoreCLIV2):

> Publish Web Projects*: If true, the task will try to find the web
>   projects in the repository and run the publish command on them. Web
>   projects are identified by presence of either a web.config file or
>   wwwroot folder in the directory.

So you could try the following code for publishing:

```
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet publish backend --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  name: PublishBackendProject
  inputs:
    command: publish
    projects: '**/backend/**/*.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/backend'
    zipAfterPublish: true
```

Comment: Thanks, @HermanCordes! Missed that part of the docs. It correctly executed the publish command for the _backend_ folder. The only thing is that it built the zips for *all the projects* (web & class libraries) in that folder. I could make the release pipe to get only the _web project_  for the drop folder, but considering that I only need to build the web project I changed the `projects:` argument to the specific path.

Comment: Thanks, setting publishWebProjects to false was the key to fixing my woes. Might just be me but it's not clear this defaults to true from the docs.

Comment: I agree, just spent an hour trying to figure out why a simple 'dotnet publish' wouldn't work for a build due to it defaulting to true and only grabbing the one web csproj in the solution.

Comment: If they are mutually exclusive it would be nice if we got even just a warning saying projects 'xyz' will be ignored, as publishWebProjects has been set to true, instead of such a silent ignore of a key configuration paramater.

Comment: what a misleading property name!!! spent hours figuring this out.

Comment: [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15874) to improve this as I too spent way too much time trying to understand the behavior here

Comment: @spottedmahn: Thanks for adding that. I strongly support your suggestion. Unfortunately, it looks like your proposal was tagged as 'stale'.