# Azure DevOps: Why does the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task not publish (zip) my Azure Functions project?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, dotnetcorecli

I have a .NET Core 3.1 solution that contains 2 Web Application projects. I am using Azure DevOps Pipelines for CI/CD and so I have the build-test-publish steps defined in an `azure-pipelines.yml` file.

The task that I am using to package the products of my two web application projects is fairly standard and based on the [DotNetCoreCLI@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#publish) task:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True
```

So far so good. This step creates two zip files, one for each web application.

But, having added a new Azure Functions project to my solution, its products are not zipped in the same way. As a result, I am unable to deploy it to Azure.

I guess the task defaults to only publishing Web Application projects. How can I make it also work on my Azure Functions project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Pipeline Publish: task DotNetCoreCLI with specific folder or project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342200/azure-pipeline-publish-task-dotnetcorecli-with-specific-folder-or-project)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that when one sets `publishWebProjects` to `True`, as I have, then the `publish` command for `DotNetCoreCLI@2` will only publish web application projects. Which, I now come to realize, is rather obvious.

The solution I've found for my need is to set `publishWebProjects` to `False` and also add `projects: '**/*.csproj'`.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: False
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True
```

Now the task creates a zip file for every project in my solution. This includes a few test projects, but I don't mind. If one does mind, one could likely list only the specific projects to be zipped in the `projects` attribute.

Comment: Pfff. I've just been debugging for a (to long) while and also found out the publishWebProjects behaviour. It's rather strange that they plainly ignore the projects argument as a default...