# DotNetCoreCLI@2 publish does not filter projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dotnet-cli

I have the following folder structure in my repository:

- Source

  - Backend

    - Module1.Api => Publishable

      - **Module1.Api.csproj** and all other project files
    - Other project folders
    - Module1.Api.sln
  - Frontend

    - Module1.UI

      - **Module1.UI.csproj** and all other project files
    - Other project folders
    - Module1.UI.sln

In our pipeline we have a step to generate the required publish packages for the **Backend** services.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: DotNet Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: True
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --runtime win-x64 --self-contained true'
        zipAfterPublish: False
        projects: 'Source/Backend/**/*.csproj' ##FILTER BACKEND ONLY
```

However projects is a wildcard to only publish Backend (`projects: 'Source/Backend/**/*.csproj'`) it still also run `dotnet publish` for **Module1.UI.csproj** which is wrong since it is in the `Source/Frontend` folder.

Do I miss something?

Comment: How about the Krzysztof`s suggestion? Have you tried it? Whether there is a project reference?

Answer (score 3):

Actually helpful was instead the following comment:

The PublishWebProjects property must be set to **false** to allow the selection of a specific project. If set to true, the value of the projects property gets ignored and all found webprojects get published.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53395041

Comment: I wish this was more obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please use working directory:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: DotNet Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --runtime win-x64 --self-contained true'
    zipAfterPublish: False
    projects: '**/*.csproj' ##FILTER BACKEND ONLY
    workingDirectory: 'Source/Backend'
```

Comment: Do I understand that when using workingDirectory then '**/*.csproj' will filter only inside that workingDirectory? I tried that and the task still keeps publishing all projects in the repo, it's crazy :X

Comment: You are correct. It will only publish from given directory. If you have an issue please create a separate question.

Comment: I got my answer thru this and  the question Anoni2 linked... unfortunately the wildcard still searches everywhere, even outside the specified WorkingDirectory - i was confused by your comment next to the projects property. Only if you change the wildcard filter to filter into your desired directory does it work fine.